# PHP idea for storing unread posts and notifications

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

So I have been playing around with a forum I am building and have been stuck on one aspect of it for a while, how to track unread posts and notifications without storing loads of data in the database. After looking at some solutions I believe I came up with a solution that may suit my needs but need a set of fresh eyes to point out what I didn't think of. Here is the architecture of my idea.

1) When a user logs in, check for posts made between current `time()` and last login `time()`.

2) If posts found, add to array, then `serialize()` array and save to member row in database.

3) Output array to user if not empty.

This way it will only check for unread posts and store on users who actually log in to the forum, instead of taking up unnecessary space holding unread IDs of inactive users. I'm still wondering if this isn't such a good idea since if the user doesn't read posts then the serialization in the database might become too large to manage.

Does anyone see a problem in my way of thinking? If so please let me know.

Comment: I suggest you to look at PHPBB's newposts section in search.php

Comment: SMF stores read topics. Yes, each user, each topic read. So, the trick, as you say, to not store all "unread" items is to store "read" items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about the space until there's actually a problem. A table storing the post ID (integer) and the user ID (another integer) will be small. Even if you have thousands of posts and thousands of users, you can safely assume that:

- a large part of the users will be inactive (one-time registrations to post something and forget the whole issue)
- even the active members will not read all the posts, but rather only a (relatively small) part of the ones that are in topics that interest them.

One other thing: don't store unread posts if you really want to minimise space. Store only the last read post in each thread. That's one record per thread per user, and only assuming the user has ever opened the thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the user logs in, but does not read posts, your scheme still marks them as read.
2. If the user logs in twice at once (as from a desktop computer and an iPad), what will happen?

What is the problem with keeping each user's view of the forum with a flag to indicate whether they read each one?  Such a mechanism is obviously useful to expand into upvoting, favorites, etc.

Comment: well storing the topic_id, and member_id in a table for each topic read per user would exponentially get larger. And what if the user marks all posts as read?

Comment: It would get larger linearly with the number of posts and the number of users. If those increase at the same rate, it will grow geometrically over time, which isn't as bad as exponential growth. If you're just storing IDs and flags, each record should be something truly puny like 10 bytes. After 2,000 users and 10,000 posts, the maximum possible size would be 200M. Sounds reasonably safe to me.

Comment: @EdR:  It is not exponential; it is linear for each of the two dimensions.  `Topic_id * member_id` for 2 million users and 20 thousand topics is only about 320 GB of storage.  At current prices, that would consume $21 of purchased disk space.  Not a big deal.

Comment: I think it would linearly get larger, not exponentially. Besides, you could always delete the references to posts older than 30 days or something.

Comment: My mistake. I decided to use a table for each topic/user and will just index accordingly. Thank you for your help.